# How to output a bright Green check mark?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

OS: Kubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64

to display above:

```
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'
```

Terminal or bash script:

```
printf '\u274c\n' # works fine.  Bright red X.
```

❌

```
printf '\u2714\n' # outputs a check mark,              
# but it is dull blue / dull grey in colour.
```

✔

Test1:

```
#!/bin/bash   
tput setaf 10; echo "tput setaf 10 Green"  # Green   
tput setaf 10; printf '\u2714\n'           # dull blue / dull grey
```

Question: In a bash script, How to output a bright green check mark?

Comment: The question is kind of pointless without knowing your terminal font, IMO.

Comment: What is the command to show a terminal font?   
The actual font being used is likely 
the same as the font that 
vanilla installs with  
```kubuntu-22.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso``` at 4.2GiB

Comment: Depends on many things, but e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/527412/is-there-a-way-to-check-which-font-your-shell-terminal-emulator-is-using-from-th

Answer (score 0):

```
$ . /etc/os-release; echo $PRETTY_NAME
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

$ tput setaf 10; echo -e "\u2714"
✔

$ tput setaf 10; printf "\u2714\n"
✔
```

... are both bright green in my bash. *(Not here at superuser though)*

Note:
Shell/Terminal menu (top right) > Properties > The active profile >
/ Colors \ -tab > `[v] Use colors from system theme`

Comment: Hi Hannu, FYI, on your computer:  
```. /etc/os-release; echo $PRETTY_NAME``` shows 
```Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS ```, but on my computer 
```. /etc/os-release; echo $PRETTY_NAME``` shows 
```Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS ``` Note the ```K``` is missing.  
This command shows the ```K``` :  
```neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'```   
OS: ```K```ubuntu ```22.04.4``` LTS x86_64

Comment: Hannu typed:  Shell/Terminal men (top right) > Properties > The active profile >
/ Colors \ -tab > [v] Use colors from system theme.  
_ Does ```Shell/Terminal menu``` = ```Ctrl-Alt-t``` ? 
Because ```Ctrl-Alt-t``` at top right says / Minimize / Restore / Close / 
not finding:  Properties > The active profile >
/ Colors \ -tab > [v] Use colors from system theme.  Navigation help requested.

Comment: The three bar menu, `///` -horisontally has the Properties choice, on 20.04, can't tell if that has changed in 22.04.

Comment: K-Ubuntu may differ quite a bit here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to have the "emoji style" appearance, output the variation selector 16 `\uFE0F` immediately after the checkmark. It will have whatever color is defined in the current **font** (which may vary between users).

If you want it to become plain text, instead place variation selector 15 `\uFE0E` after the character. It won't look as fancy but it'll be colorizable using the ANSI format codes like normal text.

```
$ printf '\u2714\ufe0f / \u2714\ufe0e\n'
✔️ / ✔︎
```

Alternatively, use U+2705 "Heavy checkmark" which usually has a green *background* when in emoji form: ✅️

Comment: Hi u1686_grawity, On this Kubuntu 22.04.4 computer, this command 
```locale charmap``` result is 
```UTF-8```  and 
```printf '\u2714\ufe0f / \u2714\ufe0e\n'``` & 
```printf '\u2714\uFE0F / \u2714\uFE0E\n'``` show dull grey check marks 
✔️ / ✔︎, A white_check_mark_Green_backgroud works  
```printf '\u2705\n'``` ✅ Thus, some success. ✅  and while at 
https://emojicopy.com/ i saw no Green_check_mark